# Convert MySQL query to Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have below query that I want to convert into Mongo then How can I

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, DATE(created_at) AS date_created_at FROM
>   "TABLE" GROUP BY DATE(created_at)

and also please explain so that next time I can do myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. I hope this will help you.

```
db."TABLE".group({
    "key": {
        "created_at": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "count_all": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.count_all += true.length;
        else prev.count_all++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In mongodb you can use the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
   {
     $group: {
        _id: "$created_at",
        count_all: { $sum: 1 }
     }
   },
   {
     $project: {
        _id: 0, date_created_at: "$_id", count_all: 1
     }
   }
])
```

which can then be converted to ruby syntax as:

```
project = {"$project" => 
  {
    "_id" => 0,
    "date_created_at" => "$_id", 
    "count_all" => 1
  }
}
group =  { "$group" =>
  { "_id" => "$created_at", "count_all" => { "$sum" => 1 } } 
}
Table.collection.aggregate([group,project])
```

For more examples, refer the **[docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/)**